# Getting the difference mother and child node (Understanding the code)

Tags: javascript

**The Question**

I have a JSON file. A small portion of it looks like this

```
var ANCESTRY_FILE = "[\n  " + [
  '{"name": "Carolus Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1832, "died": 1905, "father": "Carel Haverbeke", "mother": "Maria van Brussel"}',
  '{"name": "Emma de Milliano", "sex": "f", "born": 1876, "died": 1956, "father": "Petrus de Milliano", "mother": "Sophia van Damme"}',
  '{"name": "Maria de Rycke", "sex": "f", "born": 1683, "died": 1724, "father": "Frederik de Rycke", "mother": "Laurentia van Vlaenderen"}'
```

The exercise in the book I am reading requires me to get the difference between those people that have mothers. If they HAVE mothers take the difference between their ages. Do this for everyone and then find the average of the difference between children and mothers.

**The Answer**

```
var ancestry = JSON.parse(ANCESTRY_FILE);
function average(array) {
  function plus(a, b) { return a + b; }
  return array.reduce(plus) / array.length;
}

var byName = {};
ancestry.forEach(function(person) {
  byName[person.name] = person;
});

var differences = ancestry.filter(function(person) {
  return byName[person.mother] != null;
}).map(function(person) {
  return person.born - byName[person.mother].born;
});

console.log(average(differences));
```

**My Problem**

I have two parts on which I am confused on.

**1)**    `byName[person.name] = person;`

Why exactly are we doing this and what is it achieving? What does `byName[person.name]`mean, and why is it storing all entries of people?

**2)**

```
return byName[person.mother] != null;
}).map(function(person) {
  return person.born - byName[person.mother].born;
});
```

To my understanding the first part is checking whether or not a person actually HAS a mother or not. But how is this running? Does it only .map if someone actually has a mother? What happens if someone doesent have a mother?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can step through that code and see exactly what's going on, using the debugger built into your browser. Search for information on using your browser's "developer tools" to find out exactly how.

Comment: I **strongly** recommend that you do the above (the developer tools thing). There's nothing better than stepping through code, examining the contents of variables, etc. for understanding exactly what the code is doing. It's not difficult to learn to do that, you can probably do it in 15 minutes. It's an essential, fundamental skill, not something only advanced coders need to do.

Comment: Ok Ill try right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a high level, what that code does is:

1. Builds a map (e.g., object that maps keys to value) of people keyed by their name.
2. Filters the array of people, filtering out ones whose `person.mother` value isn't a key in the map. *(There's some hand-waving here.)*
3. Maps the remaining entries (the ones that weren't filtered out), creating a new array of the age differences.

Details and answers to your specific questions:

> 1)  `byName[person.name] = person;`
>
> Why exactly are we doing this and what is it achieving?

It creates a property in the object referenced by `byName` using the value of `person.name` as the property name and a reference to that person object as the value.

So when that loop is done, `byName` is a "map" if you will between a person's name and their person object.

> 2)
>
> ```
> ...filter(function(person) {
>     return byName[person.mother] != null;
> }).map(function(person) {
>     return person.born - byName[person.mother].born;
> });
> ```
>
> To my understanding the first part is checking whether or not a person actually HAS a mother or not.

It's checking whether `byName` has a property whose name is the value of `person.mother` and, if it does, that that property's value is *not* `null` or `undefined`. It's frankly not brilliant code.

In JavaScript, when you get the value of a property on an object (`byName[person.method]`), if the object doesn't have a property with that name, the result is the value `undefined`. If the object *does* have a property with that name, the result is the value of that property — which (somewhat confusingly) could also be `undefined`, or could be `null`, or anything else.

With `byName`, though, we know that it will either be `undefined` (there is no matching property) or a person object. `undefined != null` is `false` because when using loose equality (`==`), `undefined` and `null` are equivalent to each other. Any real object reference will give `true` for `!= null`.

So what the `filter` does is filter out entries where the `person.mother` doesn't match a property in `byName`.

> Does it only `.map` if someone actually has a mother?

Correct, the result of `filter` is a new array that only has the entries from the original array where the callback returned a truthy value.

> What happens if someone doesent have a mother?

They're left out of the final resulting array entirely.

Comment: But how does it .map if someone actually has a mother, and not .map if they dont? I mean theres no statement to check if person.mother != null {add to array}. Also You say it could be undefined, so shouldnt we say return if !=null or != undefined?

Comment: @cresjoy: *"But how does it .map if someone actually has a mother..."* All of the people have mothers. What the `filter` (not `map`) does is filter out ones who don't have mothers *on the list*, because they won't be in the `byName` map. So `filter` returns an array with only those entries whose `person.mother` value matched a property in the map. Then the code calls `map` on that new array (not the original), creating the final result.

Comment: @cresjoy: *"You say it could be undefined, so shouldnt we say return if !=null or != undefined?"* As I said in the answer: `!= null` will be `false` for `undefined`, because with loose equality (`==` and `!=`), `null` and `undefined` are equal to each other. (There's another pair of operators, `===` and `!==`, which *strict*, where `null` and `undefined` are not equal.)

Comment: I have to think about this more deeply. I've been trying to rack my brains out understanding this.

Comment: I think my confusion stems from byName[person.name]. What does that does to byName. Add a property inside of it called person? Like var byName now becomes byName = { person : ...}. It just seems all very odd

Comment: In fact whats the point of byName all together, we can simply remove all the mother:null, with filter, and then map and return person.born - person.mother.born

Comment: @cresjoy: From the answer: *"It creates a property in the object referenced by `byName` using the value of `person.name`..." So for instance, if the value of `person.name` is `"Carolus Haverbeke"`, it creates a property called `"Carolus Haverbeke"`. (JavaScript properties can have names with spaces and such.)

Comment: @cresjoy: *"we can simply remove all the mother:null, with filter, and then map and return person.born - person.mother.born"* No, `person.mother` is a string, like `"Carolus Haverbeke"`. so `person.mother.born` is `undefined` (strings don't have a `born` property). The `byName` map lets us retrieve the object (with the `born` property) based on that name. Also note that none of your example entries has `mother: null`. (If there *are* some, they'll get filtered out unless there's also an object with `name: null` or `name: "null"`.)

Comment: Ok so let me get this straight. The reason we use byName at all, is because we need to access some properties at a specific name instance. For example we can get the mother string without var byName, but we have no way of saying "hey from this mother string we need the age of the mother". So the byName allows us to access the name of that mother and then go to the age within it?

Comment: @cresjoy: Yes. In the data, the mothers are just given by name. So we look up the object corresponding to that name on `byName`.

Comment: Ok I've looked at this more closely and am still a tad bit confused with byName[person.name] = person. First byName is an empty object. Now person is also an object which is constantly changing. Person first takes the value of the first object  which happens to contain the name"Carolus Haverbeke" then on the next iteration it takes the next object holding all of its properties. So we are saying. Lets take the property "name" inside person ( hence person.name), and add that to byName. After lets set the name property within that person equal to person?

Comment: Ugh just that ONE line byName[person.name] = person, just cant seem to make sense to me, everything else makes sense now.

Comment: oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo ok i get it

Comment: Why is though if I console.log(byName[person.mother]);. Inside our filter before we map it, I get a bunch of undefined values. Shouldnt I only get undefined values for persons with mothers = null?

Comment: And if I log that after return byName[person.mother] != null;. I get nothing.. whats up with that

Comment: @cresjoy: These questions will be answered by using a debugger, not `console.log`. I compare using `console.log` to stumbling around in the dark with a torch, whereas debugging is like turning on the lights.

Comment: What do I use then? I've been using console.log and clicking inspect on my html page this whole time

Comment: @cresjoy: Again: You use your browser's dev tools. It has a debugger. Search for the information on how to use your browser's debugger.

Comment: Will do! If you have time, could you check out my new question? Many thanks!